# hexbin and ggplot in different panels

Tags: r, ggplot2, graphics, r-grid, hexagonal-tiles

I'd like to combine a hexbin plot with a ggplot in different panels in R. I can get kinda close, but it's still not working:

```
library(hexbin)
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

x1 <- rnorm(100)
y1 <- rnorm(100)

x2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.2)
y2 <- rnorm(100, 1, 0.2)


# combined hexbins
xbnds <- range(c(x1, x2))
ybnds <- range(c(y1, y2))
xbins <- 20

h1 <- hexbin(x1, y1, xbins=xbins, xbnds=xbnds, ybnds=ybnds)
h2 <- hexbin(x2, y2, xbins=xbins, xbnds=xbnds, ybnds=ybnds)

# ggplot
df <- data.frame(x1=x1, y1=y1)
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + geom_point(aes(x=x1, y=y1))

### KINDA WORKS

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(layout = grid.layout(1, 2)))
pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col=1, layout.pos.row=1))
print(g)

pushViewport(viewport(layout.pos.col = 2, layout.pos.row = 1))
plotFrame <- plot(h1, type='n', newpage=FALSE)
pushHexport(plotFrame$plot.vp, clip='on')
grid.hexagons(h1, style='constant.col', border='white', pen='blue')
grid.hexagons(h2, style='constant.col', border='white', pen='red')
```

I think one of the complications is that, as you can see, I am overlaying two hexbin objects in the same plot.  Here's what I get:

[image]

I'd like the scatter plot (ggplot) to be in the left and the hexbin plot to be in the right panel, like this (made manually):

[image]

I think one of the complications is that, as you can see, I am overlaying two hexbin objects in the same plot.

My understanding is that the hexbin and ggplot2 packages are both using the `grid` graphics system, which would seem to imply I could use one of several ways to combine the panels (e.g., [how to do that with different packages](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/#change-columnrow-span-of-a-plot)). However, the hexbin package uses `pushHexport`, which makes any of those solutions unworkable.

Comment: it's been a long time, but is there a possibility that you could use `geom_hexbin()` from within `ggplot` for your hexbin?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--I actually just did stumble on geom_hexbin(). It seems to work for this issue and is much easier to do compared to wrestling with pushHexport().